# How can I configure Google Chrome to notify about new updates available without automatically installing them?

Tags: google-chrome, updates

Well, I think the title is self-explanatory.

I prefer to **update Google Chrome** under my control. Just like, as for today, can be done on FireFox, that **reports** about "New Update available" but offers you the possibility to **start it when you desire**.

Answer (score 1):

#### I prefer to update Google Chrome under my control.

This can be done by turning off auto updates. However you will then **not** be notified about new updates and you will have to manually check for them.

Warning:

- Turning off auto-updates means you may miss an update that includes security fixes.

**Turning Off Auto Updates in Google Chrome**

> Turning off Auto-Updates on Windows
>
> To turn off auto-updates of Google Chrome on Windows, you need to
>   instruct Google Update to not update it.  To do this, you can either:
>
> 1. Use the Google Update ADM templates provided on [this page](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates) or as described in [this article](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036).
> 2. Set the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes` to the REG_DWORD value of "0".
>
> Warning: To prevent abuse of this policy, if a device is not joined to
>   an Active Directory domain, and if this policy has been set to 0 or to
>   a value greater than 77 hours, this setting will not be honored and
>   replaced by 77 hours after August 2014. If you are affected by this,
>   and still want to disable Chrome updates (NOT RECOMMENDED), you may do
>   so by using 'Update policy override' as described [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036#Policies).
>
> More information about Google Update's group policy support is
>   [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036).
>
> If you run into this error while trying to push an MSI over an
>   existing MSI:
>
> - “Google Chrome or Google Chrome Frame cannot be updated on account of inconsistent Google Update Group Policy settings. Use the
>     Group Policy Editor to set the update policy override for the Google
>     Chrome Binaries application and try again.”
>
> You will need to update your group policy settings by following the
>   instructions [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=1385049&topic=1064263).
>
> Turning off Auto-Updates on Mac
>
> More information about turning off auto-updates on a Mac network is
>   [here](http://www.google.com/support/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147176&ctx=go).
>
> Turning off Auto-Updates on Linux
>
> Google Chrome and Chromium are not auto-updated automatically on
>   Linux; your package manager handles this.

**Manually checking for Updates**:

> Q: How do I know if there is an auto-update happening soon?
>
> A: You can subscribe to the blog at
>   http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com, which lists every dev, beta,
>   and stable release of Google Chrome.

Source [Turning Off Auto Updates in Google Chrome - The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates)

---

#### Further Reading

- [How to disable Google Chrome auto update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update)

Comment: Possibly useful, but not actually answering the main question: «Google Chrome to notify about new updates».

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez It does answer the main question - the answer says it is not possible and provides a workaround.